# Get the SHA of the version used when run

Tags: r, git

Is it possible to get the SHA of the version of code which is being run in R?

I have the following code, which outputs the SHA from the master head:

```
readme<-file("info.txt")
writeLines(paste(c("Document produced using Version", 
                   paste(readChar("./.git/refs/heads/master", 10)),
                   "of code")), 
           readme)
close(readme)
```

But what if someone makes a mistake and accidentally runs the code from a different branch?  Is it possible for R to get the active branch like that? Possibly something like this, where `ACTIVEBRANCH` is figured out by some other bit of r code?

```
readme<-file("Code version info.txt")
writeLines(paste(c("Document produced using Version", 
                   paste(readChar(paste("./.git/refs/heads/", ACTIVEBRANCH, collapse = ""), 
                                  10)),
                   "of Git Instructions")), 
           readme)
close(readme)
```

Comment: I *think* you just want to run `git rev-parse HEAD` (reading the file `master` works only if the current branch is `master` *and* `master` is not a "packed" ref).  I'm not sure how one would do this in R though.

Comment: Reading `./.git/refs/heads/master` will not work anyway, even if run from master because git can also pack the refs. See [Git Docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) for more information.

Comment: :( okay, thanks anyway!  I knew it was a bit of a longshot.